# General formula for Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ar^n$ where $ |r|<1 , a\ge0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation

I'm trying to derive a general formula for $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ar^n$$

where $a\ge0$ and $|r|<1$

I know the first couple a:

$$I(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{(1-r)}$$

$$I(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^n=\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$

$$I(2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2r^n=\frac{-r(r+1)}{(r-1)^3}$$

$$I(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ar^n=???$$
assuming my math was correct. I got these by differentiating the general summation formula for geometric series. After doing it a couple more times, I can't seem to discern a pattern.

Comment: Notice each step is linked by an integral. More or less.

Comment: Or derivative If your degree of n Goes up

Comment: I know, I'm just not sure if there's a general formula for the nth derivative of the series/formula. That's basically what I'm asking.

Comment: Can you fix the title ? :)

Comment: $I(1)$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Im pretty sure a pattern exists. Seems we only need the nominator anyways. I bet this even has a name. Something pochhammer like pattern I guess. Anyways good edit. +1

Comment: I(1) needs to be same but +1 not -1

Comment: My bad on the small mistake. Thanks for the fix @mick!

Comment: Im afraid it is a bit more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^a r^n=\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{a-1}A(a,m)x^{m+1}}{(1-r)^{a+1}}$$
for $a\ge1$, where the $A(a,m)$ are [Eulerian numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number)

Comment: Tou have the skills of a thousand sharks :)

Comment: Are you able to show where this formula comes from? Or a link to where they show it? @lordsharktheunknown

Comment: Very cool. @TomHimler the sum is given on the wiki link in shark's response.

Comment: @law-of-fives Oh! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica yields $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^a \, r^n=\Phi(r,-a,0),$$
where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz-Lerch transcendant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Comment: This seems to me to merely be a restatement of the question.

Comment: Just like the zeta function can be expressed at zeta(2n) by bernoulli numbers , I expect a similar thing here.